# How to display images on Map View with an interval?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I want to display 5 images on a Map View as map overlay with an interval of 1 minute each.  I use sleep to make a delay. But it is not working. After all delay, the images are displaying altogether. How to do this? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this link. I think, it is, what you need

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

***UPD:***

Define in your activity:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private int cnt = 0;

private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {

      if (cnt < 5)
      {     
         // Display new Image
         mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 60000);
         cnt++;
      }
      else
      {
         mHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
      }
   }
};
```

and call then somwhere in onCreate or onResume

```
mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 60000);
```